# ¿No se han especificado valores para algunos de los parámetros requeridos?

Tags: vb.net, poo, vb, ms-access-2013

estoy trabajando en un sistema en Visual Basic 2010, ya he realizado algunas consultas SQL para una base de datos en ACCESS, pero en este caso uso datos de distintos formularios, entonces me arroja un error, primero les muestro el código:
Esta es una public sub que se encuentra en el formulario "funciones.vb"

```
Public Sub buscarreserva(campo As String)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cons = "SELECT " & campo & " FROM reservas WHERE " & campo & " = " & admin.txt_buscar.Text
    cmd.CommandText = cons
    Try
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            MsgBox(dr(0))
        Else
            MsgBox("Errorrrr no hay rows")
        End If
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("La reserva no se ha localizado, prueba que los datos esten correctos:   " + ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Desde donde ejecuto el código es del formulario "buscar.vb" y este es el código:

```
Private Sub btn_noreserva_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_noreserva.Click
    funciones.buscarreserva("noreserva")
End Sub
```

En el formulario "admin.vb" es donde esta el campo "txt_buscar" y ahí se ingresa el dato a buscar, el caso es que me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: imagen del error...]
Ya he probado cambiando la línea de la consulta a esto:

> cons = "SELECT " + campo + " FROM reservas WHERE " + campo + " = " + admin.txt_buscar.Text

Pero sigue sin funcionar, espero alguien pueda ayudarme a saber a que se debe el error, con sólo decirme por que se está generando podría solucionarlo.

Comment: Que representa admin en esta cadana: admin.txt_buscar.Text?

Comment: @SilvestreSilva admin representa el formulario, así se llama y es de donde se obtiene el valor del TextBox "txt_buscar"

Comment: Una duda. La línea que tienes que dice `WHERE " & campo & " = " & admin.txt_buscar.Text`... ¿no debería ser talo que así? `WHERE " & campo & " = '" & admin.txt_buscar.Text & "'"`. Y otra pregunta. ¿Cuál es el valor de `campo` cuando ejecutas el código?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes ya probé colocando las comillas simples, y sigue sin funcionar, y el valor del campo es el valor de la columna, en este caso "nresrv" (Número de reserva).

Comment: Y cuando depuras, ¿Qué linea es la que te marca como errónea?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes en la línea 25 al ejecutar este código:
`dr = cmd.ExecuteReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en la variable cons, en lugar de

```
cons = "SELECT " & campo & " FROM reservas WHERE " & campo & " = " & admin.txt_buscar.Text
```

debe ser

```
cons = "SELECT " & campo & " FROM reservas WHERE " & campo & " = '" & admin.txt_buscar.Text & "'"
```

ASegúrate también que la el campo admin.txt_buscar.Text no tenga espacios.